# Why do I need pass a comparator to construct a priority_queue when it is a lambda, but not when it is std::greater?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, priority-queue, function-object

I am reading a code sample from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue):

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> void print_queue(T& q) {
    while(!q.empty()) {
        std::cout << q.top() << " ";
        q.pop();
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::priority_queue<int> q;

    for(int n : {1,8,5,6,3,4,0,9,7,2})
        q.push(n);

    print_queue(q);

    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > q2;

    for(int n : {1,8,5,6,3,4,0,9,7,2})
        q2.push(n);

    print_queue(q2);

    // Using lambda to compare elements.
    auto cmp = [](int left, int right) { return (left ^ 1) < (right ^ 1);};
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> q3(cmp);

    for(int n : {1,8,5,6,3,4,0,9,7,2})
        q3.push(n);

    print_queue(q3);

}
```

I am not sure why `q2` does not need to be initialized? I.e. Instead of having

`std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > q2;`

in the original code, I guess we should have something like

`std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int> > q2(std::greater<int>());`

So why when we have an customized compare function, we can omit the initializer for `q2` but not for `q3` in the code sample?

Answer (score 10):

The key difference is that `std::greater` is default constructible, but closure types (lambdas) are not.

Thus, the queue needs to be given a lambda object to copy construct its comparator from as a constructor argument.

Answer (score 6):

> So why when we have an customized compare function, we can omit the initializer for q2 but not for q3 in the code sample

You have a "customized compare function" in both cases. Both `std::greater<int>` and `decltype(cmp)>` name the type of a function object. The difference between them is that `std::greater<int>` is default constructible while a lambda's type never is. So when initializing the priority queue, [this constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue/priority_queue)...

```
explicit priority_queue( const Compare& compare = Compare(),
                         Container&& cont = Container() );
```

... will (conceptually) happily default initialize `std::greater<int>()` but will fail on `decltype(cmp)()`. So you need to provide the later for copying explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

This is the constructor which is being used in your case

```
explicit priority_queue( const Compare& compare = Compare(),
                     Container&& cont = Container() );
```

So if you don't pass any argument default constructors for the template classes will be called. But the `decltype(cmp)` is not default constructible. A lambda closure type has deleted default constructor. So you need to explicitly mention `cmp()`.

In C++20, we will get these default constructors back. [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)